# What is this pneumatic connector called?

Tags: pneumatic

I'm looking into fitting ball-type inflatable equipment (eg bike tires, yoga balls, basketball ball, etc) to a 2/4 silicone tube. This will be to measure the pressure inside the inflatable, so the other end of the tube goes to a pressure sensor.

The top valve seems to have a [schrader valve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schrader_valve) compatible threading.

The bottom end seems to be called descriptively (hose fitting, air pipe fitting, tube connector, pneumatic fitting, etc), are there any DIN or other names for this?

How is each end named of how does one goes about finding such component?

[image]

Comment: They won't be called "pleumatic" anyway. See your question title!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched for "Schraeder Hose Barb".

[image]!

Answer (score 0):

Some compressors are sold with a set of them.

Commonly just called adaptors.